# Get a clean list of files transferred from rsync

Tags: command-line, files, rhel, rsync, synchronization

I'm trying to get an itemized list of files transferred by rsync. Using the -i and --out-format options, I'm instead ending up with output that looks like this:

```
3HMP1MO_001.tif
     974.68K 100%    9.58MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#1, to-check=8/10)
3HMP1MO_002.tif
     974.68K 100%    2.27MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#2, to-check=7/10)
3HMP1MO_003.tif
     974.67K 100%    1.33MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#3, to-check=6/10)
3HMP1MO_004.tif
     974.65K 100%    1.03MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#4, to-check=5/10)
3HMP81O_005.tif
     974.66K 100%  834.19kB/s    0:00:01 (xfer#5, to-check=4/10)
3HMP81GS1MO_006.tif
     974.66K 100%    2.35MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#6, to-check=3/10)
3HMP1MO_007.tif
     974.66K 100%    1.60MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#7, to-check=2/10)
3HMP1MO_008.tif
     974.66K 100%    1.21MB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#8, to-check=1/10)
3HMP8MO_009.tif
     974.65K 100% 1009.34kB/s    0:00:00 (xfer#9, to-check=0/10)
```

The full command is this:

```
rsync -irltShz --modify-window=2 --progress --exclude 'Thumbs.db' --out-format "%n" --log-file=current.log rsync://myserver/UserData/user1/ /mnt/bup/user1 2>/dev/null >filechanges.log
```

If I use -q (quiet), there is no output at all.

Using the -i option doesn't seem to make any difference.

I could grep the output, but surely I'm just doing something wrong?

```
It's `rsync  version 3.0.6  protocol version 30` on RHEL 6.2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> surely I'm just doing something wrong?

I'm guessing you've spotted this yourself by now (from `man rsync`):

```
--progress    show progress during transfer
```

I wonder how it will do that? ;P